# Create and query a binary cache in ignite

Tags: ignite

I am trying to use BinaryObjects to create the cache at runtime. For example, instead of writing a pojo class such as Employee and configuring it as a cache value type, I need to be able to dynamically configure the cache with the field names and field types for the particular cache.

Here is some sample code:

```
public class EmployeeQuery {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Ignition.setClientMode(true);
    try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml")) {
        if (!ExamplesUtils.hasServerNodes(ignite))
            return;
        CacheConfiguration<Integer, BinaryObject> cfg = getbinaryCache("emplCache", 1); 
        ignite.destroyCache(cfg.getName());
        try (IgniteCache<Integer, BinaryObject> emplCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg)) {

            SqlFieldsQuery top5Qry = new SqlFieldsQuery("select * from Employee where salary > 500 limit 5", true);
            while (true) {
                QueryCursor<List<?>> top5qryResult = emplCache.query(top5Qry);

                    System.out.println(">>> Employees ");
                    List<List<?>> all = top5qryResult.getAll();
                    for (List<?> list : all) {
                        System.out.println("Top 5 query result : "+list.get(0) + " , "+ list.get(1) + " , " + list.get(2));
                    }
                    System.out.println("..... ");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
        }
        finally {
            ignite.destroyCache(cfg.getName());
        }
    }
}

private static QueryEntity createEmployeeQueryEntity() {
    QueryEntity employeeEntity = new QueryEntity();
    employeeEntity.setTableName("Employee");
    employeeEntity.setValueType(BinaryObject.class.getName());
    employeeEntity.setKeyType(Integer.class.getName());
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    fields.put("id", Integer.class.getName());
    fields.put("firstName", String.class.getName());
    fields.put("lastName", String.class.getName());
    fields.put("salary", Float.class.getName());
    fields.put("gender", String.class.getName());

    employeeEntity.setFields(fields);
    employeeEntity.setIndexes(Arrays.asList(
        new QueryIndex("id"),
        new QueryIndex("firstName"),
        new QueryIndex("lastName"),
        new QueryIndex("salary"),
        new QueryIndex("gender")
    ));

    return employeeEntity;
}

public static CacheConfiguration<Integer, BinaryObject> getbinaryCache(String cacheName, int duration) {
    CacheConfiguration<Integer, BinaryObject> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(cacheName);
    cfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
    cfg.setName(cacheName);
    cfg.setStoreKeepBinary(true);
    cfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
    cfg.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, BinaryObject.class);
    cfg.setExpiryPolicyFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(new CreatedExpiryPolicy(new Duration(SECONDS, duration))));
    cfg.setQueryEntities(Arrays.asList(createEmployeeQueryEntity()));
    return cfg;
}

}
```

I am trying to configure the cache with the employeeId (Integer) as key and the whole employee record (BinaryObject) as value. When I run the above class, I get the following exception :

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "EMPLOYEE" not found; SQL statement:
select * from "emplCache".Employee where salary > 500 limit 5
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there anything more other than this line:

```
employeeEntity.setTableName("Employee");
```

Next, I am trying to stream data into the cache. Is this the right way to do it?

```
public class CsvStreamer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Ignition.setClientMode(true);

    try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml")) {
        if (!ExamplesUtils.hasServerNodes(ignite))
            return;
        CacheConfiguration<Integer, BinaryObject> cfg = EmployeeQuery.getbinaryCache("emplCache", 1);
        try (IgniteDataStreamer<Integer, BinaryObject> stmr = ignite.dataStreamer(cfg.getName())) {
            while (true) {
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(args[0]));
                try (LineNumberReader rdr = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
                    int count =0;
                    for (String line = rdr.readLine(); line != null; line = rdr.readLine()) {
                        String[] words = line.split(",");
                        BinaryObject emp = getBinaryObject(words);

                        stmr.addData(new Integer(words[0]), emp);
                        System.out.println("Sent data "+count++ +" , sal : "+words[6]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static BinaryObject getBinaryObject(String[] rawData) {
    BinaryObjectBuilder builder = Ignition.ignite().binary().builder("Employee");
    builder.setField("id", new Integer(rawData[0]));
    builder.setField("firstName", rawData[1]);
    builder.setField("lastName", rawData[2]);
    builder.setField("salary", new Float(rawData[6]));
    builder.setField("gender", rawData[4]);
    BinaryObject binaryObj = builder.build();
    return binaryObj;
}

}
```

Note: I am running this in cluster mode. Both EmployeeQuery and CsvStreamer I run from one machine, and I have ignite running in server mode in two other machines. Ideally I want to avoid the use of a pojo class in my application and make things as dynamic and generic as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this exception because you didn't configure SQL scheme. In your case (you don't want to create pojo object and etc) I recommend to use SQL like syntacsis which was added to Apache Ignite since 2.0 version. I sure that the following example helps you with configuration: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CacheQueryDdlExample.java

Comment: Tried to run this same example. Initially I got the error that a PUBLIC schema cannot be deleted. So I removed that clause. 
Then I got an error saying that I need to set the indexes for the cache. So I put the following line:
cacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, QueryEntity.class); // or is it Object.class? Either way I get a NullPointer at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryTwoStep(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1681)
What am I missing here?

Comment: Looked into the source code. Looks like the line "if (prepared.isQuery()) {"
 (line 1642 in IgniteH2Indexing.java) always returns false. Is this expected?
Because of this, twoStepQry is nul and we get a NPE

Comment: I realized that the 2.1 release came on 27th. Was using ignite-2.0.0. Will use the new codebase and try.